# I can't import cv2 from a conda environment

Tags: python, opencv, pip, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I installed opencv 4.3.0-dev on Ubuntu 18,04.  I built it from the latest branch on Github.  I installed it without any virtual environment activated.  When I run the following, I get the correct output:

```
python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
4.3.0-dev
```

If I create a conda environment `conda create --name foo python-3.6`
and activate it, I get this:

```
python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Neither pip list nor conda list shows the cv2 module in either case.  Where is cv2, and how can I import it into a conda virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced the same problem. I just deleted the existing openCV file and then created a conda evironment. After that i just typed:
conda install openCv
(in the terminal) 
 And the package was successfully installed in that conda environment.

Comment: Yes that works, but it's an old version.  Thank you.